# How to create a popover component in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to create a `popover` component which will have api like below:

```
<button  popover [content]="popover_content" >popover test</button>

<ng-template #popover_content>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

I have tried to some extent, pls see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj2ke4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

The problem is:

1. Content is appearing inside the button. How do I avoid it?

[image]

2. I want the content to give it some css class but when I access it I just get a comment node.

```
      @Input() set content(val: TemplateRef<void>) {
        this.popoverContent = val;
        console.log(val.elementRef.nativeElement);//this is a comment node. WHY??
      }
```

I am not sure how to solve above two problems. Would be great if someone could advice.

Comment: why not just using https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview ?

Comment: Because don't wanna. My requirement is different, plus I want to learn angular better. Also, I don't want to add a giant library just for a small component.

Comment: Fair enough, have you considered to make a component called "popover"? It's more "angular way" than your API. But if you insist to continue with your suggested API, I can answer to you that too.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no3hxn)? I've forked your code and made a couple of changes..

Comment: @EliyaCohen My api is same as material [tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview). The only difference is that my content is a template instead of a string

Comment: @NicholasK Sorry but that doesn't answer any of my two questions. I also can use *ngIf but it should work the way i am asking.

Comment: @EliyaCohen Can you see my stackblitz? I have made component popover but its not working.

Comment: @asdasd that's the thing. `ng-template` is being compiled to a comment. therefore, you can't really access its content.

Comment: If you use ionic, you can use their [ion-popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)

Answer (score 4):

Since `ng-template` is being compiled to comment, you can't actually get its content. You could try to set it to a hidden div and that might work (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj2ke4).

In any case, I made a small change with the API so it'll match the following pattern (I hope that's ok with you):

```
<app-popover buttonText="Click Me">
  <ul>
    <li>THIS</li>
    <li>IS</li>
    <li>MY POPOVER</li>
  </ul>
</app-popover>
```

It's pretty straight forward, `popover.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popover',
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.css']
})
export class PopoverComponent {

  @Input() buttonText: string;
  isActive = false;

  toggle() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }

}
```

`popover.component.html`:

```
<button (click)="toggle()">{{ buttonText }}</button>

<div class="popover" [class.active]="isActive">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Stackblitz Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovecbp

Comment: Sorry thats a big api change. My api is similar to ng-zorro's popover api. https://ng.ant.design/components/popover/en

Answer (score 2):

If you use ionic, you can use their [ion-popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) component. Otherwise, you can try a pure CSS route.

To get a basic popover working, you need a background layer with `position: absolute` as well as a *top* `z-index`. You can use `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` for convenience. It'll cover the entire screen.

```
<section class="popover-background">
  ...
</section>
```

Then you need to create the visible container for the popover, such as a modal over the `popover-background`. You can position this container however you like, it'll be the visible popover element. This container will be relative to the absolute positioned `popover-background`.

```
<section class="popover-background">
  <article class="popover-container">
    <!-- popover content -->
  </article>
</section>
```

Now, you can put whatever content you need inside the container.

```
<section class="popover-background">
  <article class="popover-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </article>
</section>
```

Assuming this popover belong to a `my-popover` component. You can choose show the content of the popover like this:

```
<button (click)="showPopver()">Show Popover</button>

<my-popover *ngIf="show">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</my-popover>
```

Additionally, you can modify this piece of code further to have dynamic popover content.

```
<my-popover *ngIf="show">
  <a *ngIf="showA"></a>
  <b *ngIf="showB"></b>
</my-popover>
```

Comment: Sorry. This doesnt answer any of my 2 questions. And I dont want to use library.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this changes that i did in the [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euxbdz) .

Added a mouseOver event but can also be done onClick

```
<div ngClass="myclass" (mouseenter)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseleave)="changeStyle($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>

 <div *ngIf = "test">
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="popoverContent"
  ></ng-container>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Very close but can you do it without the additional div in `app.component.html`. It will be bad ux for user who is using the library.

Comment: hmm, i am travelling but for css it can be fixed i guess. hope you fix it might not be a full blown solution but its a step in the right direction